# What does link transmission rate exactly mean?

Tags: links, transmission

I am very confused by 'transmission rate' and 'propagation speed'.

When we say 100Mbps, what does it mean exactly?

From what I read, the transmission rate is the amount of information that can be transformed in given period of time.

So, transmission rate = no. of bits that can be transferred in a second

Shouldn't it directly depend on the distance of transmission and propagation speed?

Without considering specific distance, what does '**per second**' in transmission rate tell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all governed by standards. 10BaseT over Cat5 will carry up to 100M at 10Mbps, and the analog propagation speed of the media is baked into this value.

Likely what you are failing to consider is the difference between the analog signal, and the digital data. Telephony devices like network cards Sample the analog signal at a specific rate (in Hertz aka Cycles-per-second) to read data off the wire. So while an analog signals time to travel a segment would be shortened if the cable was shorter, the actual amount of time it takes to read data off the line by a NIC is fixed based on the characteristics of the physical layer like the media's analog frequency.

So yes, Per second means exactly that, and it means it without regard for cabling length, provided that it is within spec. Protocols like CSMA/CD or CSMA/CA rely on this fixed relationship, to ensure that a hello signal fully propagates the media within the time it takes the sender to finish sending, so that a potential or actual collision can be detected.